# Show attachment in Linked List

Tags: list, attachments, joined-view

I linked two SharePoint lists. They are joined by column ID (like a foreign key).

When I click the Display Item of List #2, it also includes the fields of List #1.

But I can't figure out how to display the attachment from List #1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using out-of-the box list views.

An alternative - insert a list view web part on a page, and then insert a "related lists" web part.

The steps are documented here: http://www.wonderlaura.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=daba3a3b-c338-41d8-bf52-cd897d000cf3&ID=74&Web=dbb90e85-b54c-49f4-8e97-6d8258116ca0

A programmatic approach: http://www.martinhatch.com/2011/08/how-to-programmatically-add-related.html

Comment: I checked the first link you provided. Thanks for the idea I think I can make something work.

Considering each item in List #1 has a corresponding item in List #1, would it be possible to combine them in one line? So in the end I will see only one list